# Changing Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm looking into a way of altering the frame around a windows form box.  I want to make it either transparent, or get rid of it entirely.  I managed to get rid of the icon, and get rid of the maximize button, as well as restrict the user's ability to resize the window.  The bar clashes with the visual theme I'm trying to implement.

So question - Is there any good way customizing the form border & the top bar in a Windows Form application?

[image: Bar I want to edit]

Comment: you will want to either use the formborderstyle and select none or toolbar window or you are going to need to override the onDraw method and draw your form.

Comment: `The bar clashes with the visual theme I'm trying to implement` - winforms doesn't support theming. You're looking for WPF. Yes you may remove the Window Chrome and create your own, however it requires a HUGE amount of work to create a theme / custom look and feel in winforms, and even if you make it thru all the horrible "owner draw" hell, your application is going to perform horribly bad and flicker constantly due to the lack of hardware acceleration.

Comment: Either use winforms as-is, or if you really care about UX / UI, then use current, relevant, non-deprecated technology.

Comment: The answer below works, but I'll look at WPF.  I've separated all my business logic into separate projects - so I just need to draw/do the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the correct value for `FormBorderStyle`, like `None`.

Comment: @Sorceri: no, but in the form of a comment this question can not be closed.  In the form of an answer it can be marked as completed and nobody has to spend any more time on it.

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill for what you're asking, but here goes... This was a quick application I created with a circular border. It's not the entire code, but maybe you'll get the idea from it.

First, I remove the FormBorderStyle (Set it equal to None) and add a mouse handler to allow movement of the form. Code below...

```
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();
    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;


    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
        }
    }
```

Then I created a pink mesh to display as the form background. and set the TransparencyKey property to the RGB value of the background color I wanted to be transparent (in this case 255,15,255).

[image: Transparency Mesh]

Then I drew the literal controls with a graphics module.

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the starting coordinants for our graphics drawing
        int y = 0;
        int x = 0;
        // Set the end coordinants for our graphics drawing
        int width = this.Size.Width;
        int height = this.Size.Height;
        // Set our graphics options
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = XGraphics.xInterpolation;
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = XGraphics.xSmoothingMode;
        e.Graphics.CompositingMode = XGraphics.xComposingMode;
        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = XGraphics.xComposingQuality;
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = XGraphics.xPixelOffsetMode;
        // Set the colors, positions, and gradient directions then draw our background

        using (LinearGradientBrush gpxBrush = XGraphics.GradientBrushOrientation(0, x, y, width, height))
        {
            // Create our color blender object
            ColorBlend gpxBlend = null;
            gpxBlend = new ColorBlend(4);
            gpxBlend.Colors = new Color[] { Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 100, 255), Color.FromArgb(205, 255, 240, 240),
            Color.FromArgb(255, 20, 100, 230), Color.FromArgb(105, 105, 100, 255)  };
            gpxBlend.Positions = new float[] { 0.0F, .45F, .55F, 1.0F };
            gpxBrush.InterpolationColors = gpxBlend;
            // Draw our background
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(gpxBrush, x, y, width, height);
        }

        // Set the end coordinants for our graphics drawing
        width = this.Size.Width-5;
        height = this.Size.Height-5;

        using (LinearGradientBrush gpxBrush = XGraphics.GradientBrushOrientation(0, x, y, width, height))
        {
            // Create our color blender object
            ColorBlend gpxBlend = null;
            gpxBlend = new ColorBlend(2);
            gpxBlend.Colors = new Color[] { Color.White, Color.Gray };
            gpxBlend.Positions = new float[] { 0.0F, 1.0F };
            gpxBrush.InterpolationColors = gpxBlend;
            // Draw our background
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(gpxBrush, x+5, y+5, width-5, height-5);
        }



        width = this.Size.Width / 2;
        height = this.Size.Height / 2;
        using (LinearGradientBrush gpxBrush = XGraphics.GradientBrushOrientation(0, x, y, width, height))
        {
            // Create our color blender object
            ColorBlend gpxBlend = null;
            gpxBlend = new ColorBlend(2);
            gpxBlend.Colors = new Color[] { Color.White, Color.Gray };
            gpxBlend.Positions = new float[] { 0.0F, 1.0F };
            gpxBrush.InterpolationColors = gpxBlend;
            // Draw our background
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(gpxBrush, x + width / 2, y + height / 2, width, height);
        }

        width = (this.Size.Width / 2) - 5;
        height = (this.Size.Height / 2) - 5;
        using (LinearGradientBrush gpxBrush = XGraphics.GradientBrushOrientation(0, x, y, width-5, height-5))
        {
            // Create our color blender object
            ColorBlend gpxBlend = null;
            gpxBlend = new ColorBlend(4);
            gpxBlend.Colors = new Color[] { Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 100, 255), Color.FromArgb(205, 255, 240, 240),
            Color.FromArgb(255, 20, 100, 230), Color.FromArgb(105, 105, 100, 255)  };
            gpxBlend.Positions = new float[] { 0.0F, .45F, .55F, 1.0F };
            gpxBrush.InterpolationColors = gpxBlend;
            // Draw our background
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(gpxBrush, (x + width / 2)  +7, (y + height / 2) + 7, width - 5, height - 5);
        }
    }
```

[image: No Background or Form Border]

As you can see, there is no border now and the edges are transparent. Just make sure to add a button to exit the application since there isn't an 'X' option anymore! ;)

Hope this helps you somewhat!